# Chef on Windows Not Automatically Running

Tags: windows, chef

I have chef-client installed on a windows node and if I run:

```
get-windows service *chef*
```

I see the service is started. Yet my recipes don't seem to be run unless I open a command prompt or powershell prompt and manually type in:

```
chef-client
```

Obviously that's not what we want - it should run by itself.

Given the service is installed and running how can we troubleshoot why its not working?

Thanks
Brad

Comment: How long are you waiting? By default it only runs every 30 minutes?

Comment: @coderanger sorry for the delay in replying. I've waited *days* and nothing happens. Yet if I go to a command or powershell prompt and type in chef-client it takes off and starts running recipes.

Comment: Check the Chef log files.